# Vim code debugger suggestions (step through etc)

Tags: vim, gdb

I'm a fairly new web developer, doing most of my work in JavaScript / CSS, but I will be doing work in PHP soon and I wanted to get a head start on debugging software.

My editor of choice is Vim, so I'm looking for suggestions for a debugger workflow, either a Vim plugin or a separate program, preferably something that could match the feature set of Eclipse or Visual Studio, but if that doesn't exist I'd like to know.

I found several Vim plugins online:
   - [VimDebug](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=663) looks nice but only supports Python, Perl and Ruby.
   - [vdb](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1703) looks promising but also confusing (at least to me)
   - [VimDebugger](https://github.com/taxilian/VimDebugger) is in early stages

I also found [gdb](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/), which was the only non-IDE debugging tool I found (if anyone has found others I'd love to hear about them!), as well as [vim-debug](http://jaredforsyth.com/projects/vim-debug/), although development seems to have stalled on that one.

In short, does anyone have any working experience with the above tools? Or have a better suggestion? Does anyone have a working workflow debugging code with Vim?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: For PHP, [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) is the debugger you'll most likely want to use, and [Vim can interact with it](http://developers.blog.box.com/2007/06/20/how-to-debug-php-with-vim-and-xdebug-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the relatively new and actively developed Vdebug: 
https://github.com/joonty/vdebug

It talks to debuggers supporting the DBGp protocol (which includes PHP with Xdebug and also many other dynamic languages).